# Can I vectorize the following?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a m file `fun.m` such that `fun(t,x,g)` gives a particular value. However, `fun` is a black box, I do not know what exactly it does, as that m file may be written by another programmer. Here, `fun` accept scalar input of t and x; g is a function. What I can input is `t`,`x` and the function `g` which are decided by user. However, if I decide to use `g` to be specific function, I won't change the function, i.e. if I decide to use `g=@(y)y.^2`, then I want to write a program allowing another user to input a vector `t` and a scalar value of `x`. For example, if the user choose `t=[1,2,3,4]` and `x=5`, my program can output `fun([1,2,3,4],5,@(t)t^2)`, while if the user choose `t=[1,2,3,4,6]` and `x=10`, my program can output `fun([1,2,3,4,6],10,@(t)t^2)`.

Originally, I use for loop to solve the problem, and I want to use `arrayfun` if possible, what I write is as follow:

`g=@(y)y.^2`
`TEST=@(T,t)arrayfun(@(s,x)fun(s,x,@(y)g(y)),T,t)`,

Unfortunately, `TEST([1,2,3,4],5)` gives error, saying that dimension does not match. I want to ask: is it possible to use `arrayfun` to do my task? If so, how to correct the above code to get the result?

Comment: Why not just loop it? There's really no benefit to `arrayfun` here

Comment: Do you want the numerical output of `fun([1,2,3,4],5,@(t)t^2)` or exactly `fun([1,2,3,4],5,@(t)t^2)` as a string?